# Ongoing Scent Sensitivity Issue

Tags: human-resources, employees, sickness

Ok, so my issue has been going on for over a year, with no resolution. I'm hoping someone can provide constructive advice for getting things resolved.

I work in a corporate office, and they already have a scent-sensitive policy in place. I've been here for 4 years, and the same poster has been on the wall the entire time. For the last 14 months, there have been coworkers who have been using scented products while in the office. One lady sprayed so much perfume I was gagging, I approached her gently, she then used the same scent lotion daily all over her body and didn't understand why that was still a problem.

I have brought it to my manager's attention, the department director's attention as well as HR's attention. Two emails have been sent out by the director, just generic "hey we have this policy" type emails, literally the same verbiage both times. One person (the original and main offender) stopped, but recently I've noticed more people using highly scented products in the office.

It almost happens daily. After the most recent email was sent out (about a month ago), the very next day, someone had a wax warmer at their desk, I had to go home sick, and was violently ill for two days. I have a note from my neurologist that I am sensitive to scents and they trigger migraines for me, and it is noted in my employee-file.

Since it has been going on for such an extended time period, and all parties are aware of what is going on, is there anything else I can do? I am beyond frustrated that other people's inability to follow the rules that are physically posted keep effecting my job.

Answer (score 13):

People don't follow posted rules. They need active training, possibly from an outsider. You need to request this. Explain why the written policy is ineffective. Do the request in writing (email should work).

And even if people get back to you in person, or want to have an in-person meeting with you, or call you back over the phone, summarize what was said retroactively via email.

And if your employer is still unwilling to pay for it or take the time out of people's schedules, you may need an actual lawyer to make the request on your behalf.

Comment: +1 especially for the suggestions to raise additional awareness through training if posters and e-mails are not sufficient to get the point across that some people are more sensitive than others.